# Query by date and time only, without year using SQLite

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I am storing birthdays in my SQLite database, they are dates converted to my own timezone from another timezone, every hour I want to query my database to get the dates that are the same day and hour

```js
// Stored in DB:
const date = parseFromTimeZone(`2020-${bdayReply} 13:42:00`, { timeZone });

// Query
const birthday = await Birthday.findOne({ where: { date: new Date() } });

// Generated query
query: SELECT "Birthday"."id" AS "Birthday_id", "Birthday"."userId" AS "Birthday_userId", "Birthday"."date" AS "Birthday_date", "Birthday"."birthdayConfigGuildId" AS "Birthday_birthdayConfigGuildId" FROM "birthday" "Birthday" WHERE "Birthday"."date" = ? LIMIT 1 -- PARAMETERS: ["2020-02-03T07:42:00.005Z"]

// Output of new Date() at the time of running the query
2020-02-03T07:42:00.023Z

// Example of record active in my DB at that point (date var from earlier)
2020-02-03 07:42:00.000
```

The ORM I'm using allows for raw queries as well, now I was wondering what my query should look like to return the above record in the example, or maybe I can use a date library like date-fns to convert the new Date() to match the format of the database, what would that look like?

Comment: You should name your ORM.

Comment: The ORM I'm using is TypeORM, could it help me or would your answer below be my best bet?

Comment: yes probably according to the documentation of TypeORM which is not talking about selecting part of the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use an SQL raw query, it should looks like this :

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE MONTH(my_date) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(my_date) = DAY(NOW())
```

In SQLite, the syntax is :

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE strftime('%m',my_date) = strftime('%m','now') AND strftime('%d',my_date) = strftime('%d','now')
```

Comment: In SQLite this gives me `Result: no such function: NOW`

Comment: Looks like the syntax is `date('now')` in SQLite. https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/functions/now.php

Comment: @Daniell I just edited to add the SQLite syntax of the query.

Comment: You don't need `date('now')`, just `'now'` as an argument to `strftime()` works.

Comment: Thank you, to add the hours I could add `AND strftime('%H',my_date) = strftime('%H','now')`? or would it be better to add another column which tells me I notified the user that day?

Comment: If it is for birthday, why do you check the date every hour ? Once a day is enough.

Comment: I am not sure about the behaviour in different timezones, might be a bit out of the scope of this question but if daily is a better approach, what would be the best local time to run this query at daily?